# How do you deal with the 'Expression has changed after it was checked' on Dynamic loaded content?

Tags: angular, angular8

I am using material tabs to show a bunch of forms in my app. I have a main form that shares some of its data with secondary forms, each one in a different tab, that are added and deleted dynamically. To share the main form's data, I use a service which contains a behavior subject that the other forms subscribe to. Here is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    private MessageSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});

    getMessage = this.MessageSource.asObservable();

    constructor() {}

    setMessage(message: any) {
        this.MessageSource.next(message);
    }
}
```

On my other forms I receive the data and update the form with the new values with this:

```
        this.dataFromMain.getMessage.subscribe(message => {

            if (message.user) {
                this.form.patchValue({
                    user_name: message.user.name,
                    user_address: message.user.address,
                    user_city: message.user.city
                });
            }
            if (message.placeOfDecl) {
                this.form.patchValue({
                    placeOfDecl: message.placeOfDecl
                });
            }
            if (message.dateOfDecl) {
                this.form.patchValue({
                    dateOfDecl: message.dateOfDecl
                });
            }
            if (message.items) {
                this.form.patchValue({
                    item_id: message.items.id,
                    item_code: message.items.code,
                    item_desc: message.items.desc,

                });
            }
        });
```

Now, because the secondary forms are often created after the main form is filled, when I place the above code on the `ngOnInit` function, the new values doesn't show up on the new form.

When I place the above code on the `ngAfterViewInit` function, the newly created form gets updated but I also get the  `"Expression has changed after it was checked"` error.

To solve this thing I ended up using the same code on both `ngOnInit` and `ngAfterViewInit`.

I suspect that I am doing something wrong or there is something that I am missing. Repeating the same code in two places doesn't seem right. Does it?

Here is a blitz... 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/my-dynamic-tabs

Comment: can you also add sample code on how you implemented your mat-tab

Comment: I added a link above...

Comment: The generic answer to this question is "don't modify values of your component from within the lifecycle hooks."

Comment: How it is done then? Can you point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is twofold. First, `MessageSource` is a `BehaviorSubject` - and a specific characteristic of `BehaviorSubject` is that it provides a value immediately upon the call to `Subscribe`.

The second issue is that you are calling `Subscribe` in the `OnInit` and/or `AfterViewInit` where it should be called in the constructor to your component.

**What is this error?** This specific error is caused when a property of the component is updated during the change detection cycle (see [Angular Lifecycle Hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)). If a component property is updating as a side-effect of change detection, then it's likely that the DOM and the property will not be in sync any longer - hence the error being thrown. It's telling you that you have written bad code.

The reason you are getting this error is because, while the call to `Subscribe` specifies a lambda, the fact that you are calling `Subscribe` on a `BehaviorSubject` means that the lambda is immediately called, *before the next line of code after `Subscribe`*.  It's the same as if you didn't have the call to subscribe in the first place, and just skipped straight to `MessageSource.value`.

*The effect is to update the component during the change detection cycle*.  The reason it works when you `pipe` the `delay` function is that `delay` queues the subscribe for execution after the conclusion of the lifecycle. It doesn't actually solve your design problem, just papers over it.

Some questions you need to consider:

1. Why do you need a `BehaviorSubject` in a service? This is not generally good design practice.

   a. If the intent is to have a property `CurrentMessage`, you can dispatch with the subject altogether.
2. Why aren't you subscribing to the service in one of the following places/times:
   (a) when the call for data is needed
   (b) the constructor of the component
   (c) the `set` of the service property (if it's supplied later, not as a dependency)?

Comment: The reason I used a `BehaviorSubject` is because I need multiple components to change, transmit and receive a particular set of shared data. That is why I chose a service. 
Now, if I am not wrong the constructor is the first one that is called upon the creation of the component, so this is before any lifecycle hook is called. So, I think this is not the place to go. I need the data to be in place when the DOM starts loading, so they can be used. I think I need a kind of a resolver, but I don't know how to implement it. I am quite new in Angular, I am trying to figure all this out...

Comment: Actually, subscribing inside the constructor solved the issue! Now I am trying to figure out why this works...  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @gothaf, it works because the constructor is called prior to the lifecycle methods `OnInit()`, etc. - the purpose of change detection is to figure out when a property on your component has changed, and updating the DOM as needed. If you do this before change detection, there is no error (that's how it's supposed to work). If you update *during* change detection, it's an error.

Comment: Yes, all is clear now! Thank you for helping me out with this, I appreciate your time!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please tell when your `BehaviorSubject` is fired ?

Why don't you use `EventEmitter` in your service

```
 private messageSource EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

getMessage() {
    return this.messageSource;
  }

setMessage(message: any) {
    this.messageSource.emit(message);
  }
```

and then in your component

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.dataService.getMessage()
      .subscribe(message => //initialize your form here);
  }
```

Comment: This only works if the new form is created first and the data are sent after... or I am doing again something wrong. 

I have create a sample blitz. Check it if you wish... https://stackblitz.com/edit/my-dynamic-tabs  @Shank

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution posted somewhere on github... I inserted a delay before subscribing to the observable like this:

```
 this.dataFromMain.getMessage
              .pipe(delay(0))
              .subscribe(message => {

       //rest of code
```

Now, this is only called inside the `ngAfterViewInit` function and the error is gone.
But, I think this is only a workaround after all...